# I want to save to mysql database, send an email then do a post, all using one button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a shopping cart and want to send an email confirming the order before forwarding the data to the payment system, for example PayPal.

Client put items in shopping cart and when ready I show a confirmation page with all details of the order. There is a button, Go to pay, that make a post to the selected payment system.

But before the post is executed, I would like to update the order data in my MySql table and also send a "Thank-you-for-the-order" email.

My first idea was to post to my server, update the table, send the email and do a curl to the payment system. But then they don't get transferred to the payment system in their browser to complete the payment.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: I know the Paypal API has functionality that will send processed transaction data to a url on your server. I haven't used it in a while and I think they have a new REST API.

Comment: " send an email confirming the order **before** forwarding the data to the payment system," thats putting the cart before the horse - what if they dont pay?

Comment: @Gohn67 its called IPN(Instant Payment Notification), still very popular with paypal

Comment: @Dagon: We confirm the ORDER, not the payment.

Comment: @Gohn67: We use IPN to track payments. But we offer some other payment systems also.

Comment: In the confirmation email we include a link to the shopping cart, if they want to select another payment system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How you should probably do things

*EDIT: Although I'm leaving this section here for now, I did make a false assumption about your process, so perhaps the next section is more beneficial*

I have not used online payment systems in any of my own projects, but I just took a look at the PayPal docs to confirm something. The payment process seems to go like this:

1. Get user order and payment details
2. Pass payment details to Paypal
3. Direct the user to the approval URL so that the user can approve the payment
4. They are redirected to your site by PayPal, with a payment ID
5. You then confirm the payment by querying PayPal with the payment ID

Most payment systems I've encountered online have had a similar process (from what I can see as an enduser). From what you're saying, it seems like you want to email the user and update your database at step 2, when you have not confirmed that a payment actually took place. I would suggest that instead, you perform the table update and email during step 5.

So wait until whatever payment system you are using has confirmed the order, and update at that point, as part of the same process in which you query PayPal to confirm the order (And you can make sure your actions depend on them having actually paid you!)

### How you can do what you're asking to do

Going back to the guts of your question though. If you do want to execute your own server side code while directing them to the external system, I'd suggest you send an Ajax request when they submit the form. This will call the script where you do your work in the background, and the user will still be redirected to the payment provider.

*Edit: I should mention the snippet here is using jQuery*

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {

    // Do your ajax stuff here


});
```